# Problem accessing all the bytes on NFC Tag with OMNIKEY 5426G2 reader using C# to send PC/SC commands

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare, contactless-smartcard, pcsc

I am having trouble reading and writing to different NFC tags with **OMNIKEY 5426G2**.
I can read and write the first 16 pages (4 bytes each) but the moment I send a command to read the 17th page - I get an error  `0x6A 0x82`  which means that address does not exist.

For example sending  `0xFF 0xB0 0x00 0x06 0x04`  gets me the 4 bytes on the 6th page
But when I do  `0xFF 0xB0 0x00 0x10 0x04`  - I get  `0x6A 0x82`  in return saying that this address does not exist.

All the tags that I use have this problem - different NTAG's, Mifare Ultralight C tags but ICODE SLIX tags are fine.

P.S. The same PC/SC commands work perfectly fine with **ACR1252** reader so this is something related to **OMNIKEY** reader. Maybe some extra commands are missing.

P.P.S. Strange thing is that I can read/write all the bytes and pages by using a demo version of this library https://smartcard-api.com/buy-smart-card-api-library-license/
And since they are also using PC/SC commands - it clearly says that I am missing something.

Please help me understand what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: I have never heard of a tag with ‚pages‘ as small as 4 bytes. Are you sure, you read them completely? If they are bigger, fewer would be needed for reaching the capacity.

Comment: @guidot What I meant by "pages" are 4byte lines that are usually swown in all NFC readers. NTAGs and similar tags have one big chunk of data, not like Mifare classic, with their 16 Sectors and each Sectors contains 4 Blocks and each block contains 16 bytes.